# Java full EE on Heroku application server or servlet container (best practices)

Tags: jakarta-ee, heroku, glassfish-embedded

lets say I need a "full" Java EE applicaton on Heroku.
What would be the "better" way to go? (when it comes to performace and memory usage)

1. embedded glassfish server
2. use embedded jetty and build the "EE functionality" with frameworks etc.

Hope my question is clear enough and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about heroku, but what you're trying to do is to put application server functionality into another container type, e.g. a servlet container - which is almost always a bad practise.

If you like to use JavaEE features, then go and use a JavaEE application server. If not, use other frameworks.

We had the same problem by being locked to Tomcat 7, but liked to use JavaEE features, so we ended up creating a huge WAR file with most of the JavaEE jars in it - still, this was not a good practice, but we had not much of a choice there.

But if you have the chance to select the environment, I would strongly recommend to take a full JavaEE application server, benefit from all its services which come out of the box and keep your application small and handy.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I guess one can transfer this answer to Heroku. It’s just that you have to use an embedded server and my thought was that maybe glassfish is "overkill" for a Dyno (Heroku virtual box)

Comment: You **can** use an embedded Glassfish, but I would **not recommend** to build your application that way. I guess you had a reason to choose that container and then it's the best to use the available techniques of that container instead of trying to put other containers into it, which will almost certainly result in further problems.

Comment: Yes you are right I have my reason: Due to the nature of Heroku, you have no other choice than to use an embedded container.